# Android push notification banner not showing up in some devices

Tags: android, push-notification

I tried to push notify with `NotificationCompat` :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            b.setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setSmallIcon(this.getResources().
                        getIdentifier("ic_launcher", "mipmap", this.getPackageName()))
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                        this.getResources().
                        getIdentifier("ic_launcher", "mipmap", this.getPackageName())))
                    .setTicker("God Reacts")
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setContentTitle(data.get("lineOne"))
                    .setContentText(data.get("lineTwo"))
                    .setContentInfo("Spread the message !");

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this,getMainActivityClass()),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            b.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) 
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify(1, b.build());
```

But in few devices (Samsung,MI etc) the notification banner is not shown.
The notification slides in the action tray with sound and vibrate.

But in few devices it is shown perfectly when the app is closed/background/foreground.The device where it's popping up correctly uses marshmallow.Is is due to specific OS ? Or is it device related issue? What extra I need to add?

Comment: Just some special cases, some devices may install notification clean app, they can clean your notifications. I have met this problem before and it totally made me crazy. maybe you can check it.

Comment: @Spark.Bao I don't think that was the case.I checked it on 2 real devices without notification clean up app.I don't understand for what reasons these problems occur

Comment: Did you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522254/get-android-notification-to-appear-as-banner ?

Comment: @josealfonsomora yes I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems was in the settings for some devices.

Need to switch on '`Floating notifications`' from setting -> app -> notifications.

Comment: Can you add some more details to your solution?

Comment: @arul there is nothing more to it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem may arise in some devices of nougat version due to Battery optimization.
**eg.** Samsung Galaxy S8 and S8+, Oneplus, xaiomi etc. but in Android version of nougat,
**You can try this once**, for that you have to check settings once,

**step 1:** Goto settings >

**step 2:** search for **"Battery optimization"** >

**step 3:** from here, tap on **"apps not optimized"** and switch to **"all apps."**

**step 4:** search for **your app** (of which you are not getting notification)

**step 5:** tap on your app name and set it as **not optimized** so that it can receive notification.

**OR**

**step 1:** Go to Settings > Apps

**step 2:** Click the : Menu in top right, select > [Special Access]

**step 3:** Select > **Optimize Battery Usage** >

**step 4:** Click the dropdown menu towards the top of the screen that says: "Apps not optimized [v]" -> change to [All Apps]

**step 5:** select your app and change it "Not optimized".

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But the problem persist in older versions as well ( for example kitkat)

Comment: alright!! will try something else and update you if it worked.

Answer (score 3):

in chinese devices like MI or OPPO ,etc . The system shut downs notification services for non-whitelisted apps .So there is nothing much you can do about it . Simply request them to whitelist your app ( bleak chance of happening in general ) or use a hack of always keeping your app in memory somehow , say by running some blank background service 24*7

Comment: My app does run some background service

Answer (score 1):

First Try with minimum notification property . Try following code which is working fine in my app . If it works than you can debug your code by enabling on by one property of notification .

```
 private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Touchrooms Notification")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue when notification used an icon or image and couldn't load that icon/image. You can easily test it by changing those lines that sets icon from resources to load icon by `res_id` like below:

```
b.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail);
b.setLargeIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

Your current approach for loading these icons may fail on those devices and as a result, notification will have sound and vibration but no visible content will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the **"Do not disturb"** option in the settings of the device is still on. If so, turn it off and you are good to go.